# OpenVINO 2022.3.0 Raspberry pi 4 can't install openvino-dev

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi4, openvino

I'm trying to install openvino-dev on my RasPi4 (Raspbian OS 64-bit), through pip(python3.9.2) and getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openvino==2022.3.0 (from openvino-dev) (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for openvino==2022.3.0

How can I fix it?

I tried to install it through

```
pip install openvino-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVINO 2023.0.0](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/releases/tag/2023.0.0) now has support for ARM processors such as the Raspberry Pi4 and Apple Silicon (M1/M2/etc).

You can install the OpenVINO runtime with `pip install openvino==2023.0.0`

And the OpenVINO dev tools with `pip install openvino-dev==2023.0.0`

If you're looking to build OpenVINO, you can check out [this guide](https://www.samontab.com/web/2023/06/how-to-build-openvino-2023-0-in-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-and-run-an-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to the fact that there isn't a OpenVINO runtime package available for Raspbian OS on PyPI. If you carefully take a look at the Operating System requirements in the [openvino pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/openvino/), Raspbian OS is not under the supported entries and therefore not fully validated. I am not aware of a fix for an install on Raspbian via pip.

Some alternatives to get OpenVINO Runtime on Raspbian OS:

1. [Install OpenVINO Runtime for Raspbian OS](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html)
2. [Build for Raspbian Stretch OS](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/master/docs/dev/build_raspbian.md)

**Note:** the 2022.3 version of the runtime archive only includes ARM CPU plugin. If Myriad plugin is needed please build OpenVINO from source.